# to tap someone to get things done

Tags: word-usage

> In soccer, a flagship sport associated with Adidas since the 1950s,
>   general manager Markus Baumann says he now has more control over
>   sales, design, and sponsorship budgets and **doesn’t need to tap
>   headquarters staffers to get things done**.

[*How Adidas Got Its Game Back*](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-09-29/how-adidas-got-back-in-the-game)

What exactly does "to tap" mean here. In informal British English, "to tap" means **to ask or beg (someone) for money ⇒ he tapped me for a fiver.** Maybe this is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it means that he does not need to ask for additional support from people who work at the headquarters.  Look at this definition found in [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tap):

> Exploit or draw a supply from (a resource)

Examples (also from Oxford):

‘This facility will be demonstrating how the research and skills base of the city's university can be tapped to produce real business returns.’

‘We then tapped into the support from the Rural
Fire Service.’

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/tap) to "tap".

I think the most relevant here would be to "drain" or "nominate" (depending on how you understand the sentence).

Comment: @Rathony I don't change tags when I'm not sure, since I know the edit will be reviewed and I'll be able to know which ones I should have used